# i am getting Terminated due to timeout for a particular test case in which my loop executes 100000 times .can anyone help me solving this problem?

Tags: python, stack

Problem: i am getting Terminated due to timeout for a particular test case in which my loop executes 100000 times .can anyone help me solving this problem?

QUES.    You have an empty sequence, and you will be given  queries. Each query is one of these three types:

```
1 x  -Push the element x into the stack.
2    -Delete the element present at the top of the stack.
3    -Print the maximum element in the stack.
Input Format

The first line of input contains an integer N, . The next N lines each contain an above mentioned query. (It is guaranteed that each query is valid.)

Constraints 



Output Format

For each type 3 query, print the maximum element in the stack on a new line.

Sample Input

10
1 97
2
1 20
2
1 26
1 20
2
3
1 91
3
Sample Output

26
91

//My Code

# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
stack=[]
top=-1
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    x=list(map(int,input().split()))
    if x[0]==1:
        top+=1
        stack.append(x[1])
    elif x[0]==2:
        top=top-1
        stack.pop()
    else:
        print(max(stack))
```

Test Case for terminated timeout:
100000
1 86627537
1 938778873
1 495914598
3
3
3
3
3
3
1 507065127
1 230961732
3
1 641113507
1 123729858
1 706231036
3
1 218881566
1 759861012
3{-truncated-}

Comment: Could you post a link to the test case data? [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/) will allow you to upload a file and give you a link.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are always printing the max value, it probably makes sense to keep a separate sorted array. I can only guess that calling `max(stack)` is "timing out" in this test case because it is searching an unsorted list.

I'm guessing this is a lesson in algorithmic complexity. Maintaining a sorted array and pulling the max value has a lookup time of `O(1)` where calling `max()` is dependent upon the implementation.